# Reverting a Google Transaction

Tags: google-play-store

My daughter has accidentally purchased a stack of coins from **Google Play Store** for a very heavy amount. Is there a way to revert this transaction?

Comment: Contact the Google Play support, they usually handle refunds without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use this form to submit a refund request from google - https://support.google.com/googleplay/contact/play_request_refund_apps?ctx=about_refunds_on_google_play&rd=1

In most cases google does give you your money back but you need to explain them about the accident, the best is to clearly state the issue and letting them know the act was done by a kid so that you can actually make a point.

I got the same situation quite sometimes back, it took about 30 days to get a reply from google support but eventually i got the refund. :)